# Sound delay in MediaPlayer

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

I have a problem, or rather a question.

I'm making music player app, that can play additional sound effects using buttons during music playing in background. I've already done that, but the delay between clicking button and playing sound is larger than i'd want it to be.

I've found a tip on Stack to use SoundPool, but i don't feel any changes between doing it with soundPool and another MediaPlayer. Don't know if I did everything propertly, that's why i'm asking you guys.

```
mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.music2);

soundPool = new SoundPool(1, AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, 100);
        HashMap<Integer, Integer> soundPoolMap;
        soundPoolMap = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();
        soundPoolMap.put(1, soundPool.load(this, R.raw.plate, 1));

 public void playMusic (View w) {

    if(mediaPlayer.isPlaying())
    {
        mediaPlayer.pause();
        playBtn.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.pause);

    }else {

        mediaPlayer.start();
        playBtn.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.play);

    }
}

public void playDeep (View w) {

    if(mediaPlayer.isPlaying())
    {
        MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.deep);
        mp.start();
    }
}

public void playPlate (View w) {

    if(mediaPlayer.isPlaying())
    {
        soundPool.play(1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0);
    }
}
```

Comment: did you solve it?

Comment: Not really, all I could do there was cutting sound to the possible maximum, yet sound delay was still here. It wasn't also a debice problem, as i checked it on few available phones and more or less problem was still here.

Comment: yee i'm too can't resolver it. Possibly I found solve for API24+ stackoverflow.com/a/42582893/7449805

Answer (score 0):

You should be playing empty mp3 on background(?).
I played 1 hour empty mp3 using following code, then mp3 was immediately played.

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    BasicPlayer player = new BasicPlayer();
    player.open(new File("emtpy 1h.mp3"));
    player.play();

    BasicPlayer realPlayer = new BasicPlayer();
    realPlayer.open(new File("i want to play it.mp3"));
    realPlayer.play();

    //...
}
```

I don't know why it works, but it works.